# Enable dropdown hovers only after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap built in dropdowns, and they show on hover. The user should know they are available when the arrow/eject icons shows up. I want these dropdowns only available and able to hover once the user clicks/chooses a row from the table. The fiddle I have below shows them permanently, which isn't what I need here. The arrows show as they should, but I can't figure out how to disable/enable the dropdown hovers. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**jQuery**

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    //enable dropdowns after row click
    $('.dropdown-menu').show();

    //now show hover icons for dropdowns
    $('.glyphicon-eject').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YSmK7/6/

Comment: Not sure I get it? Is this what you're trying to do -> http://jsfiddle.net/YSmK7/7/

Comment: @adeneo Well this disables the dropdowns, but on click I want them active on hover again. Not stuck displayed.

Comment: @triplethreat77 please go through and upvote/accept answers that were helpful for you or answered your question.  I just noticed that on your last three questions you have not accepted any answers.  If none of the answers are adequate please indicate in the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you take away the `dropdown` class initially that will stop the dropdowns.  If you add the `dropdown` class after the click then the drop downs will be activated.

Everywhere where you have `<li class="dropdown">` change it to `<li class="beforedropdown">`

HTML

```
<li class="beforedropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
```

jQuery

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
   //now show hover icons for dropdowns
   $('.glyphicon-eject').show();
   $('.beforedropdown').addClass('dropdown');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YSmK7/8/

**Update**

And if you don't want to be able to click on the links to bring up the drop down menu either you need to do the following.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="">
```

Remove the value out of all the `data-toggle`s on all your `.dropdown-toggle` links.

http://jsfiddle.net/YSmK7/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.toggle()` method instead of `.show()`
Or bind a `.hide()` to the event that should remove the menus, such as mouseout().

Comment: @petyuno1 Can you give an example on the Fiddle above? I'm not sure I understand, without manipulating the js.